# bash: write all lines starting with one of strings

Tags: string, bash, grep

I have a set of strings and want to write out all lines of a file that start with either of these.

Tried this that I found on the internet but that writes out the whole file... May I ask for a help? Thanks!

```
grep -Ev "^(58|11518|11909|11910|11911|11912|11913|11914|11915|11916|11917|11918|11919|11920|11921|11922|11923|11924|11925|11926|12055|12056|12060|12102|12103|12104|12105|12106|12107|12108|12109|12110|12111|12112|12113|12114|12115|12116|12117|12118|12119|12120|12121|12122|12123|12124|13813)" dead_end1_model.inp > newfile.txt
```

Comment: I guess that no lines are matching the regular expression, so all lines are getting printed. You need to show us a [mcve], some lines from your file, the patterns (a file or a variable) and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: `want to write out all lines of a file that start with either of these` perhaps a simple typo of using `-v` when it shouldn't be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current invocation of `grep` only prints the inverse `-v` of the matches. I.e. any line **not** starting with any of those strings gets matched.

By your description you want to match the lines that do start with any of the strings, so just remove the `-v` from the invocation.